# How to implement a Modal Navigation Drawer with material.io on iOS

Tags: ios, material-design, navigation-drawer, side-menu

According to the material.io documentation, the Modal Navigation Drawer should be used for sideMenus on mobile device but their api almost only contain drawers for the bottom, `MDCBottomDrawerViewController`, `MDCBottomDrawerPresentationController` etc. What about the side drawer? I checked but didn't find a `MDCSideDrawerViewController`.

The following code uses the `MDCBottomDrawerViewController`, but the problem is that the `MDCBottomDrawerViewController().contentViewController` presents my table from the botton instead of the from the side.

Set up for bottomDrawVC:

```
var bottomDrawerViewController: MDCBottomDrawerViewController = {
    let drawer = MDCBottomDrawerViewController()        
    drawer.isTopHandleHidden = false
    drawer.dismissOnBackgroundTap = true
    return drawer
}()
```

The presenting of the bottomDrawVC:

```
@IBAction func toggleSideMenu() {
 let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TableViewController")
 let size = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
 bottomDrawerViewController.contentViewController?.preferredContentSize = size 
 bottomDrawerViewController.contentViewController = vc
 present(bottomDrawerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

As I can't seem to find info in the docs, how does one present a modal side menu with material.io on iOS?

Comment: I have run into this same problem as well. Material's documentation on it is incredibly unhelpful. Have you found a solution yet, @KarmaDeli?

Comment: Last I checked, modal side menu is in beta and unavailable. Instead, I used ContainerViewControllers.